# how to get recursive calls from a method

Tags: java, recursion, call, sudoku

I just finished writing a sudoku solver. It has two classes, a console solver, and a gui solver.
The console solver has a method called solve, which solves the sudoku recursively. The gui extends the console solver and also uses its solve method. It is easy to keep track of each recursive step, by printing out the sudoku field inside of the method, before doing another recursive call, like this:

```
System.out.println(field);

// solve next cell
if (j < 8) solve(field, row, column + 1);
else solve(field, row + 1, 0;
}
```

But how do I go about displaying the changes in the field in a gui?
I use a JTable to display the sudoku field in the gui.
Currently I just display the result, but not the steps leading to it, which seems kind of boring.

Here's Some more relevant code:

```
/* solve button action listener/handler */


    solveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

             /* solve the sudoku and display it 
              * in solve table.
              */
                fieldToTable(field, solveTable); //put sudoku field in display
                try {
                    solve(field, 0, 0); // Solve starting at [0,0]
                } catch (SolvedException d) {
                    /* SOLVED */

                    }

                        } //End of action handler
            }); // End of action listener


    /* Done with solve button action listener */
```

Comment: Could you post more relevant code?

Comment: My first thought is to have the GUI implement some interface that can update your necessary information, then your recursive calls can pass along that interface instance and call the interface method with the appropriate information (at least cell location and value)

Comment: Yassin: Just edited post with code used in the sudokuGUI class

Cricket: Im sorry, but I do not understand any of that. I'm a newbie..

Answer (score 0):

You could "solve" it in a Thread and update the Board in each iteration. Here's a basic apporach using a Thread - a more sophisticated one would probably use a SwingWorker.

**Disclaimer:** You might need to add additional checks, make some variables final and so on to make this work.

```
  solveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         /* solve the sudoku and display it in solve table. */
         fieldToTable(field, solveTable); //put sudoku field in display
         //Disable button while solving
         solveButton.setEnabled(false);
         //Start Thread to do the work
         new Thread() {
            public void run() {
              try { 
                 solve(field, 0, 0);
              } catch(SolvedException se) {
                //What now - reenable button                 
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> solveButton.setEnabled(true));
              }
            }
         }.start();                    
       } //End of action handler
    }); // End of action listener
```

And change your solve() to update the board on each call:

```
public void solve(Field field, int x, int y) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> fieldToTable(field, solveTable));

    // YOUR SOLVE LOGIC
}
```